# Google Sheets - Importxml - Content is Empty

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula

I was wondering to scrap some data from [this webpage](https://csgostash.com/skin/271/AK-47-Redline).

[image]

Initially I didn't have any problems with the prices but when I try to scrap the volumes data with the short xpath (like i did with prices) importxml throws me the empty content error.

I'm using the following formula:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://csgostash.com/skin/271/AK-47-Redline";
"//*[@id='DataTables_Table_0']/tbody/tr[5]/td[5]")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think using the importXML is the right approach. Consider using [importHTML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093339?hl=en).

Using the below formulate I get the entire table:

`=IMPORTHTML("https://csgostash.com/skin/271/AK-47-Redline","table",1,"en_US")`

If you want just the columns 1, 2 (price), and 5 (volume), you can use adjust formula to capture as:

`=Let(allData,IMPORTHTML("https://csgostash.com/skin/271/AK-47-Redline","table",1,"en_US"),CHOOSECOLS(allData,1,2,5))`

[image]

Comment: Mmm i think i can work with that but it's not precisely what i'm looking for. I mean the goal is to scrap the individualized values as i did with the prices (e.g. taking the value "1" separately), surely it should be possible by adjusting the formula (wich i don't have the less idea how to).
I started to check if it is possible with the Choose function but i don't find the way.

Comment: mmdMMmmm what does "taking the 1 separately" mean? You want to only see the price when the volume is 1? Seems like a lookup would be easy enough. Use this below formula to figure it out. I named a couple columns then looked up where the volume was 1 and returned the 2nd column. Don't forget to click accept as your question is essentially entered (your content is not empty).

`=Let(allData,IMPORTHTML("https://csgostash.com/skin/271/AK-47-Redline","table",1,"en_US"),nameCol,CHOOSECOLS(allData,1),priceCol,CHOOSECOLS(allData,2),volCol,CHOOSECOLS(allData,5),XLOOKUP(1,volCol,priceCol))`